# Lets have Myth of the Month back

Tags: discussion, myth-of-the-month

I think we are slowly receiving more traffic. And we need another incentive.

Let's try again!

Comment: Any suggestions for some myths to cover the next few months?

Comment: Someone just chose a myth and create a post. It doesn't really matter what story you chose, just chose one and we'll read it. Here's a list of suggestions: http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/255/monthly-mythology-reading-group-would-you-be-interested Here's another list http://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/what-are-good-sources-to-introduce-people-to-mythology

Comment: I'm not very regularly active on here, so I may miss the next one, but if you want extra ideas, Geseriad (Epic of King Gesar) is a good candidate. Not very well known in English speaking world, truly epic (pun intended) in size, has links to many other things (Hinduism, Taoism, Buddhism), popular among TONS of peoples (Tibet, China, Mongolia, fUSSR), and pretty well academically researched (kinda).

Answer (score 5):

To get the ball rolling, I propose:

**King Arthur**

There are many possible questions around the many interpretations and versions of the Arthurian myths.

Admittedly, being born and bred in Glastombury, this is my home turf.

Comment: Do you have a link to a text of a story about king arthur?

Comment: Perhaps even [tag:arthurian] as a whole, even the ones *sans* Arthur?

Comment: There are any number of published works on Arthurian legends and, yes, those without Arthur, e.g. Gawain and the Green Knight, would work well.