# Myth of the Month #4: Sumerian Mythology

Tags: discussion, myth-of-the-month

[As per Bleh's suggestion](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/lets-have-myth-of-the-month-back), let's do another myth of the month.

This month, rather than focusing on a specific story, I thought it would be cool to focus on Sumerian mythology in general. The reason for doing this is that there is a really cool website, ETCSL (Electronic Text Corpus of Sumerian Literature), that contains [a fantastic collection of Sumerian mythology/literature](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/cgi-bin/etcsl.cgi?text=c.1*#). ETCSL lists about twenty stories, and each story is the length of a page, so this month's reading is very manageable.

Happy reading!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the resource included by Hamlet, there are some more interesting links which speak of Sumerian mythology:

1. [Sumerian Mythology, by Samuel Noah Kramer[1944, 1961]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/ane/sum/)

Comment: Please feel free to edit and add more resources in the answer.  (I have converted it into a CW for the same purpose) :)